# How to get snowpack to look inside a package for subpath

Tags: node.js, snowpack

I am building a snowpack app right now, and I would like to import `socket.io client` in  the frontend (For intellisense and offline dev testing). However, `socket.io` only exports the backend materials when using `import ... from 'socket.io'`.

Normally, I use

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js';
```

Which gets all the correct files and exports, however, when building with snowpack I get this error:

```
Package exports for 'C:\dev\JS\Node+Browser\foo\node_modules\socket.io' do not define a './client-dist/socket.io.js' subpath
```

Which fails the build, stopping everything.

Right now, my `snowpack.config` is really bare bones:

```js
module.exports = {
    buildOptions: {
        out: 'dist/client'
    },
    mount: {
        "src/client": "/"
    }
}
```

All of the rest of my modules run fine, because they are all imported with only `import ... from 'module-name`. I understand what the error is saying, but I cant find anything online or thing of anything to solve it.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is a "hacky" fix that I think is messy and can not be used for larger projects.

I patched this by editing the `package.json` of the `socket.io` package (In `node_modules`) to use a temporary export alias that was exactly the same as the real directory path:

`node_modules/socket.io/package.json`

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": [
      {
        "require": "./dist/index.js",
        "import": "./wrapper.mjs"
              },
      "./src/index.js"
    ],
    "./client-dist/socket.io": "./client-dist/socket.io.js",
    "path-to-other-modules": "same-path"
  },
```